# Change the Uri of a instance of HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, uri

I have an instance of an HttpWebRequest that I'm intercepting in an event.
I would like to edit the url before the request is sent but I can't find a way of doing this.
The property RequestUri is read only.

I've thought of a few ways but can't seem to find a working solution:
-Using reflection to set the value ?
-Creating a new request and then cloning all properties. not sure how to do that.

Comment: I think you're going about it in the wrong way. If you have to resort to all kinds of tricks and reflection, then it should be clear to you that you need to re-think your design/approach. Why is it that the HttpWebRequest gets the wrong url in the first place? Maybe you need to have an intermediate step that figures this out before you get the HttpWebRequest involved.

Comment: Agreed but unfortunately I don't control the creation of the HttpWebRequest. I'm using a DataServiceContext that generates a HttpWebRequest from a linq query.

Answer (score 1):

If you think in terms of the HTTP protocol, each request is stateless / unique.  The only way to link one request to another is programmatically through something like Cookies, but to the HTTP protocol itself the request is unique.

I think the HttpWebRequest object was designed with this in mind.  Each HttpWebRequest represents one unique call to a URL and you build up the parameters for that call.  If you want to do another request to a different URL you would create a new HttpWebRequest and pass it the state information you are using, ie: Cookie container, header information etc.

The long winded answer to this is the object is designed to have a read only url and the only way to handle it is to:

1. Use a little reflection hack, such as you have already done, if you absolutely need to use the given HttpWebRequest object you have.
2. Create a new HttpWebRequest  (WebRequest.Create()) and copy your state information over to the new request.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`RewritePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa5wkk6d.aspx) to do this.

F.e.

```
HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("newurl.aspx");
```

Comment: This is an HttpRequest object. I'm talking about HttpWebRequest.