# I want to Modify the URI of Request in .Net But HttpWebRequest properties are read only. How can I modify this?

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I have gone through discussion of stack overflow link
[Change the Uri of a instance of HttpWebRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015265/change-the-uri-of-a-instance-of-httpwebrequest) 
But it suggest some reflection hack . Kindly elaborate it?

Can't I process creating a different Request by just changing URI everything else will remain same?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you really want to intercept the request, and change it's uri, then just create a new request and copy over everything else from the old request into this one, as one of the answers in your SO link suggested.